# How to send native tokens from one wallet to another using javascript

Tags: polkadot-js

I want to send native enjin token on the enjin relay chain from my wallet to another wallet using a js script. I am using @polkadot/api package.

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider, Keyring } from '@polkadot/api';
import "dotenv/config";

async function main() {

  const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.relay.blockchain.enjin.io');
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
  const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' })

  const PHRASE = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_RELAYCHAIN;
  const newPair = keyring.addFromUri(PHRASE);

  const unsub = await api.tx.balances
    .transfer('enCxhF3S8ANdQ7dh75yar3ZrXKd9PMDLCHJmvNPSKgm38E5nh', 1)
    .signAndSend(newPair, (result) => {
      console.log(`Current status is ${result.status}`);

      if (result.status.isInBlock) {
        console.log(`Transaction included at blockHash ${result.status.asInBlock}`);
      } else if (result.status.isFinalized) {
        console.log(`Transaction finalized at blockHash ${result.status.asFinalized}`);
        unsub();
      }
    });
}
main().catch(console.error).finally(() => process.exit());
```

Here is the code snippet coppied mostly from https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.tx.subs
Can someone explain what i am doing wrong and how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

What is exactly the issue? What's the error? My recommendation, try running a local testnet using this zombienet:

- https://docs.substrate.io/test/simulate-parachains

Then try sending a token from one account to another account. Once you get that to work with the Polkadot/Rococo Relay chain then move to trying it on the Enjin Relay chain.

Make sure you have sufficient balance.

Here are some sample snippets that I have used:

```js
// Import the API, Keyring and some utility functions
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from "@polkadot/api"
const wsProvider = new WsProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:9944");
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
import { Keyring } from '@polkadot/keyring';

export const simpleTransfer = async () => {
    const BOB = '5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty';

    // Construct the keyring after the API (crypto has an async init)
    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });

    // Add Alice to our keyring with a hard-derivation path (empty phrase, so uses dev)
    const alice = keyring.addFromUri('//Alice');

    // Create a extrinsic, transferring 12345 units to Bob
    const transfer = api.tx.balances.transfer(BOB, 12345);

    // Sign and send the transaction using our account
    const hash = await transfer.signAndSend(alice);

    console.log('Transfer sent with hash', hash.toHex());
}
```

```js
const wsProvider = new WsProvider("wss://rococo-statemint-rpc.polkadot.io");
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
const mnemonic = "magnet foil stay blue brown core unveil require exotic electric quick judge"
const pair = keyring.addFromUri(mnemonic, { name: 'TEST002' }, 'sr25519');
console.log(keyring.pairs.length, 'pairs available');
console.log(pair.meta.name, 'has address', pair.address);
const receiver = 'GvFpQe1ACuSsMk1jn7RsRLzhYwYt92LLieDnUr1azbFsj9Z'

export const sendAll = async () => {
    const transferExtrinsic = api.tx.balances.transfer('5C5555yEXUcmEJ5kkcCMvdZjUo7NGJiQJMS7vZXEeoMhj3VQ', 123456)
}
```

Hope that is a start for you to start troubleshooting.